# lost connection with the app to play videos

Tags: video

Say, I use StormPlayer to play videos in my PC. Once I changed the folder name of StormPlayer, where I installed StormPlayer.

From then now, StormPlayer is still able to play videos if I open StormPlayer and choose videos files. But if I open video files by double clicks directly, they can't associate themselves with StormPlayer, thus unable to play, unless I open StormPlayer manually. How to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried changing the name back?

Comment: yes, useless. files and the initiating exe file lost connection

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling StormPlayer?

Comment: this will work. but i havent that installation file any more